# Как в M.Access запустить sql файл

Tags: access, sql

Здравствуйте, хочу перенести базу из SQLite в Access.
Генерирую SQL файл- всё ок. А вот выполнить его на Access не могу.
Гугл не помог, к сожалению.
С кодировкой в SQL файле тоже проблемка. В базе словарь на немецком языке, где есть умляуты (Ü,ä...) которые не сохранились в таком виде.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть в данной ситуации?

Comment: а не проще из sqllite экспортировать во что-нибудь более переносимое?
например в csv или xls(x). В Access кажется даже функция импорта была из этих форматов

Answer (score 1):

1. Для выгрузки используйте UNICODE кодировку
2. Для загрузки SQL скриптов можно воспользоваться утилитой  http://www.rsdn.ru/article/files/progs/BatchAccess.xml

Answer (score 0):

Если есть ODBC-драйвер к sqlite, то я бы попробовал импортировать базу из Access.